# How to disable an option from dropdownlist if its value already exists

Tags: php, mysql

I have to select all courses to let user insert what selected to another table called curriculumcourses.

When user select courses there is a drop down list to insert courses in groups

what I need to do is that if the group is in the curriculumcourses table the option of that group will be disabled

The problem with my code right now is that I couldn't select from  curriculumcourses because there is a while loop to fetch courses data

Here is my code

```
<?php

$curid=isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : '';
$sqlcheckgroup =  ("SELECT * FROM curriculumcourses  WHERE curriculum_id='$curid'");
$rowgroupcheck = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlcheckgroup);

$sql1 = ("SELECT * FROM courses ORDER BY course_code ");
$result = $mysqli->query($sql1);


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {   
?>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"> <label>

        <select name="select[]"  id="select[]">
          <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Please Select</option>
          <option value="0">No Group</option>
          <option value="1" <?php if (!(strcmp(1, $rowgroupcheck ['set_number']))) {echo "disabled=\"disabled\"";}?>>Group One</option>
          <option value="2" <?php if (!(strcmp(2, $rowgroupcheck ['set_number']))) {echo "disabled=\"disabled\"";}?>>Group TWO</option>
          <option value="3" <?php if (!(strcmp(3, $rowgroupcheck ['set_number']))) {echo "disabled=\"disabled\"";}?>>Group Three</option>
          <option value="4" <?php if (!(strcmp(4, $rowgroupcheck ['set_number']))) {echo "disabled=\"disabled\"";}?>>Group Four</option>
          <option value="5" <?php if (!(strcmp(5, $rowgroupcheck ['set_number']))) {echo "disabled=\"disabled\"";}?>>Group Five</option>
        </select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store them in an `array`.

```
$rowgroupcheck = array();
while($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlcheckgroup)) {
    $rowgroupcheck[] = $res['set_number'];
}
```

Then check them while displaying the options. -

```
<option value="2" <?php if (in_array(2, $rowgroupcheck)) {echo "disabled=\"disabled\"";}?>>Group TWO</option>
```

Execute the query -

```
mysqli_query($createdlink, $yourquery)
```

Comment: I got this Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given in C:\Apache\htdocs\xxx\selectedcourses.php on line 77

Comment: You first have to execute the query.